# Compute the upcoming task date until the system date is crossed using excel or sheets formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to Compute the upcoming task date until the system date is crossed using excel or sheets formula

[The live example is shown here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJyDjgz1HPK5uHUE3yjSLbBxDhZRXOze_WKOUT6ixiw/copy)

"F2 cell must have a formula that can compute the due date
based on A2, B2, C2, D2.
If the current system date is 9th the F2 will show the next due date as Jan 8, 2021"
"F2 cell must have a formula that can compute the due date
based on A2, B2, C2, D2.
If the current system date is 9th the F2 will show the next due date as Dec 15, 2020

After crossing the system date ie 16th Dec 2020, if I look at the cell F3, it must show the value as
2021 June 15"

[image]

I have tried with

```
=if(day(today())>=day(F2),eomonth(F2,D2-1)+day(F2),F2)
```

Comment: If you have an entry with Start Date=Dec 2,2020, DateOfMonth=20, and Frequency=2, what would it's Expected Due Date be today (on Dec 10, 2020)? Feb 20,2021? Or Dec 20, 2020?

Comment: Dec 20 because the system date has not crossed Dec 20. If the system date is dec21 then its value must be Feb 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have formulas that seem to work.  I've put it into [a working sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a07c4qaG6re8ZxhOnAZoqCytpjOi75bUbyzo0wpcTiA/edit?usp=sharing) for you to test. At the moment, I'm using an intermediate column, column E, to show the first due date, but this can be incorporated into the formula to remove that requirement.

For testing, I've also replaced NOW(), with a variable (set in H2), so that we can test using different effective system dates.

The main formula for the current due date is effectively:

```
=IFERROR(IF(NOW()<=E7,
  E7,
  eomonth(E7,(rounddown(datedif(E7,NOW(),"M")/D7)+1)*D7-1) +C7  ))
```

where E7 is the first due date, D7 is the frequency (month increment), and C7 is the "date of the month".

The current formula for the first due date, in E7, is:

```
=iferror(eomonth(A7,-1+D7)+C7)
```

It is possible that this should be incremented by one month, in the case where the start date, A7, is in the middle of the month, greater than the "date of month" value.  This can be handled by adding some IF logic, if that is what you want.

[image]